# Publishing and installing an Outlook 2003 Add-In

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005, .net-2.0, outlook-addin, outlook-2003

I have a solution with 5 projects in it, one of which is a Windows Form Project. They all are part of the Outlook Add-In. I tried publishing the 5 projects and installing them, which seems to work fine. The only problem is, after installing I see the entry in the Start Menu but only for the Windows Forms project. When I start it, the Form is displayed but not Outlook.

Also, if I open Outlook and look into COM-Addins, I don't see my Addin. How can I publish/install my Addin so it will load automatically when Outlook starts?

Answer (score 0):

Did you create an Outlook 2003 VSTO project?  Are your registry entries deployed and is LoadBehavior set to 3?

Deploying Application-Level Add-Ins (2003 System)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms269007.aspx